# Looking for advice on the best way to automatically change a user role in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone have advice on the best way to modify the code so that it changes the user's role no matter what role they currently have, instead of just for the customer role? Thank you in advance.

```php
// Code to change user role when purchase a woocommerce product
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase' ); 
function wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {
    // Get order object and items
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $products_to_check = array( '229', '6934' );
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $order->user_id > 0 && in_array( $item['product_id'], $products_to_check ) ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );
            // Get all current roles for the user and store them in an array
            $user_roles = $user->roles;
            // Remove all current roles
            foreach ( $user_roles as $role ) {
                $user->remove_role( $role ); 
            }
            // Add new role
            $user->add_role( 'editor' );
            // Exit the loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is outdated: `$order->user_id` is outdated and replaced by `$order->get_user_id()`… Also you can get the WP_User Object using directly `$order->get_user()`.